# Is there any syntax like : #{systemProperties['environment_variable_name']} to get the system variable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, system-variable

Does using #{systemProperties['environment']} in the applicationcontext.xml file of Spring return the value associated with environment?

Or is there any way to ge the system variable value in the spring applicationcontext.xml file.

Comment: Are you talking about system properties or environment variables? Those are two different things, you know...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<s>When I remember right, then there is a difference between:</s>

You can access the system properties in different ways:

- `#{systemProperties['databaseName']}`
- `#{systemProperties.databaseName}`
- `${databaseName}`   //$ instead of # !!

<s>With `#{systemProperties['databaseName']}`  you have access to system-system-properties.</s>

With `#{systemProperties.databaseName}` you have access to the system properties readed for example from the command line (`-DdatabaseName="testDB"`).

With `${databaseName}` you have access the the properties from the properties files loaded and provided for example by the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer **and to  the system prooperties too**

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['java.version']}")
private String javaVersionMap;

//Dont know how
//@Value("#{systemProperties.javav.version}")
//private String javaVersionDirect;

@Value("${java.version}")
private String javaVersionProp;
```

---

```
//-DcmdParam=helloWorld
@Value("#{systemProperties['cmdParam']}")
private String cmdParamMap;

@Value("#{systemProperties.cmdParam}")
private String cmdParamDirect;

@Value("${cmdParam}")
private String cmdParamProp
```

You can use all of them in a `@Value` annotation or the config.xml files (`<property name="databaseName" value="#{systemProperties.databaseName}"/>`)

Comment: Does anybody know the right names for this two different kind of system properties (the system provided and the command line provides ones)?

Comment: no such thing exists. The command line version sets "real" system properties: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#standard . Such a difference does only exist in Maven : System Properties (command line) vs Project Properties (pom.xml)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: I have tested it and you are right (It seams that my records were wrong). -- I have corrected the answer

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this kind of thing is to use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which can be configured to use the system properties.

I also noticed that the [Spring 3.1 M1 blog entry](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) talks about new stuff for accessing configuration information from "the environment".  Of course, that is only a milestone ... not a production-ready release.