# How to load a System property in Spring using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue with Spring, I have to load a system property using an annotation.

I'm trying this approach:

```
@Value("${mySystemProperty}")
private String mySystemPropertyValue;
```

But when I make this:

```
System.out.println("mySystemPropertyValue="+mySystemPropertyValue);
System.out.println("system.mySystemProperty="+System.getProperty("mySystemProperty"));
```

It returns:

```
mySystemPropertyValue=null
system.mySystemProperty=myValue
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

EDIT

I'm trying all, but I always get in return a null value for every System property.

I also tried:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

But the "environment" variable is null...

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285978/is-there-any-syntax-like-systempropertiesenvironment-variable-name-to-g

Comment: Where is the `System.out` placed? Also is the `@Value` on a Spring managed bean or just a regular thing.

Comment: I tried both @Value("#{systemProperties['mySystemProperty']}") and @Value("#{systemProperties.mySystemProperty}"), but i always get null in return.

Comment: My property name has a "-" character (the exact name is "my-property"). But I don't think that it depends on it...

Answer (score 5):

Try something like :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityContextConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Value("#{systemProperties['your.system.property']}") 
    private String property;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your configuration class contains some `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. I beleive it is `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` as you need this bean to have properties resolved.

Some explanation from Spring javadoc:

> Special consideration must be taken for @Bean methods that return Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BFPP) types. Because BFPP objects must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can interfere with processing of annotations such as @Autowired, @Value, and @PostConstruct within @Configuration classes. To avoid these lifecycle issues, mark BFPP-returning @Bean methods as static.

That is why `@Autowired` and `@Value("#{systemProperties['your.system.property']}")` don't work within the config class.

---

So to solve your issue just make method that returns `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` static or add such method if you don't have it

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

And make sure that there is no more non-static BFPP-returning @Bean methods.
Also you can move BFPP beans to separate `@Configuration` class.

---

**UPDATE**

Simple app demonstrating usage of `@Value` within `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
public class SimpleJavaConfig {

    @Value("${java.version}")
    private String property;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ApplicationContext app = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SimpleJavaConfig.class);
        System.out.println("|" + app.getBean("propertyBean") + "|");
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pcc() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public String propertyBean() {
        return property;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand how can I read the property with using the bean PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. Can you please show me an idea? Thanks

Comment: @AlessandroC You don't need to do with `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` anything special. Just add it to the context and it will resolve property values. This bean is required to make `@Value("${mySystemProperty}")` work.

Comment: I have added the bean like your indication, but if I try to make a variable with @Value("${my-property}"), it still returns null... I don't understand why!

Comment: @AlessandroC Have you passed `my-property` value somehow? e.g. -Dmy-property=myValue

Comment: @AlessandroC I've added simple example to the answer. Try it

Comment: of course, the property value is passed to the startup of the application as a system property. It works if I make System.getProperty("my-property"); I tried your suggest, but I had a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException